# Create a networkx bipartite graph with a Stack Overflow dataset > 5m nodes, need advices and recommendations

Tags: python, bigdata, visualization, networkx, sna

I'm doing a project about data visualization and sna and I'm working with the **Stack Overflow temporal network dataset** (http://snap.stanford.edu/data/sx-stackoverflow.html). The dataset represents the interactions between users on Stack Overflow, ex. User A answered User B's question in a particular time. I have already done heatmaps tracking the most prominent users activity and the other idea I have is to represent the dataset as a bipartite graph. 
I'm new to NetworkX and I would like to get an advice to know if I am thinking right and if it's possible to interpret my idea, and what is the best way (examples with big datasets and similar issues would be very helpful).
So,
I have User A and Useb B as nodes and the edge between them is the time. I have ~5m nodes. I would like to represent the connections as a bipartite graph because of the structure the dataset has. The data is unbalanced, >95% are users that asked/answered only once. My idea of a visualization was to get something similar to this:

[image]

Is it possible? If it is, can you give me an example how to do the visualization. What is the best way to represent it?

I would appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure to have fully get your problem. By definition, in a bipartite graph `G=(V,E)` with `V=(V1,V2)` there are no edges between the nodes of each set. Who are `V1` and `V2` in your case?

Comment: V1 and V2 are user A and user B